# Quick OOP Question - PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, function

In OOP, sometimes you see something similar to this:

```
$memberID = $system->members->memberID();
```

I was wondering and totally confused on the part where it is `->members->...` How does that work?

For example, lets say I have a class that I call up called `$systems`, then how can I put `->members->` after it to run the members class?

I only know how to do something along the lines of this:

```
$system = new system();
$memberID = $system->memberID();
```

But I would like to know how to do this:

```
$system = new system();
$memberID = $system->members->memberID();
```

Thanks!

-- UPDATE --
Here's a little update, thanks to everyone who helped me out this far!  You guys really pointed me in the right direction, I actually have a great answer to my own question! :)  And thanks to the moderator who edited this question, I'm sorry I wasn't familiar with the bbcode syntax.

I wanted something to automatically make the new classes, for example calling ->members-> would be automatically included using __get() rather then having to do manually put in something like "new members()".  A little difficult for me to explain, but I hope you got the basics of it.

Anyhow, here is the code that I use:

```
<? class system {

public function __get($name){
    $file = 'lib/'.$name;
    if(file_exists($file)){
        require_once($file);
        $classname = $name;
        $this->$name = new $classname($this);
        return $this->$name;
    }else{
        die('Class '.$name.' could not be loaded (tried to load class-file '.$file.')');
    }
}
```

} ?>

Now, if I were to do something the lines of this:

```
$system = new system();
$system->members->functionHere();
```

It would automatically create a new instance of the members class and require the file from the lib folder.

If this is against the rules then I apologize. I just wanted to post this for anyone who came across this question while searching Google, because I know I always land up here when googling things!

Answer (score 3):

the `$system` variable holds an object which has a property named `$members` which itself holds an object which has a property `$memberID`

```
$system = new system();
$system->members = new Members(); // or whatever it must be
$system->members->memberId();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you see something like that, you know that someone has most probably done something wrong!

In order for this code to work, you need to grant public access to a member variable of an object (the former storing an object).

To grant public access to such a member variable is in most cases bad practice. The variable should only be accessible through a getter (at least, it will still violate the LoD).

This code breaks the principle of encapsulation and the LoD (Law of Demeter).

[EDIT]

Why it is almost certainly a mistake:

A) Granting direct public access to member variables is in most cases a mistake, because **it makes the public interface of your class rigid** (hard to change). If you have a getter, you can change the implementation of the member anytime, the getter will still be the same and you don't need to change the call from anywhere. **You can NEVER write a proxy** for direct access to a variable! Writing a proxy for a getter on the other hand is easy!

B) Granting direct public access to member variables is in most cases a mistake, because **you let everyone talk to a class inside a class** directly! This will most probably lead to **higher maintainance costs** when the public interface of any of these two classes changes.

[/EDIT]

Comment: Outside of doing extra stuff to the variable, I see no reason to use a getter - it's a useless middle-man. It's understandable when you're doing a certain procedure to a variable after getting it, but making a function access a variable, and having to name everything differently just for that?

Comment: @Zirak: You obviously do not understand the principle of encapsulation and the law of demeter.

Comment: You also do not think further than the 'now', which is a big mistake in engineering!

Comment: @Zirak you just newbie. read about encapsulation more and about interfaces. As example, this book: http://www.amazon.com/Objects-Patterns-Practice-Experts-Source/dp/143022925X/

Comment: @Galen: Would you care to explain your disagreement?

Comment: @OZ_ - While I can't hope to counter "you just newbie", if you don't actually use getters in your design at all, there's no reason to add them. If you do use, even one, then you have a reason. The major thing I dislike about a giant encapsulated thing is that it takes such a longer time to do very simple things to it. Your privates are private, but there's no reason (if you have no sensitive stuff) to keep your publics private.

Comment: If you'd use a getter instead of direct access to the member, it would still violate the Law of Demeter. So I disagree with you as well, but my disagreement is totally different.

Comment: @GodsBoss: Yes, you'd still violate LoD.

Comment: @Zirak Some time ago I would be agree with you, but now I understand that it's mistaken theory :) Read that book, there explained well about encapsulation. There only 430 characters left and I can't explain enough (and my English is far of fluent for big discussions).

Answer (score 0):

`members` is object property of `system` and is also an object that contains method `memberID()`.

To assign property to your object, simply do something like this:

```
class System {
  function __construct() {
    $this->members = new Members();
  }

  // etc
}
```

or

```
$systemObj = new System();
$systemObj->members = new Members();
```

It really really depends on the context you wish to use :)

As @markus mentioned, properties must be declared public if you're accessing them from outside. Also, using setters/getters is often much better ...